# Renaming files with special structure in a quick way

Tags: terminal, filesystem, macos

I checked out the solution [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/236213/renaming-files-names-in-bulk-any-smarter-solution), but it is not adressing my problem too well, because it does not use the specific structure of my naming.

I have a collection of files, enumerated and named in a systematic way, for instance

> filep-x

where x is a number that can be quite large and p is a marker for a "makrocollection". I would like to copy all files in such a makrocollection as a template and automatically rename all files copied as

> fileq-x

With other words, is there an option that I can replace names automatically using the terminal (like it is possible in many editors) without working with additional documents?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be a job for `pax`, assuming that there is a consistent naming convention.

```
cd directory

pax -rws/filep/fileq/ filep-* /path/to/copy/directory
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually this can be done with a `bash` loop - not the quickest, but simple. In terminal type:

```
for f in filep-* ; do mv -iv "$f" "$(echo "$f" | sed 's/p/q/')" ; done
```

Explanations:

- `for f in filep-* ; do`  -> for all files called `filep-anything`, do the following
- `mv -iv A B` move (=rename) A to B, while telling what you do `-v` and asking for confirmation before overwriting an existing file `-i`
- were going to move a file `"$f"` (quotes for addressing problems with e.g. spaces in file names) to:
- `$( $echo $f | sed 's/A/B' )` print the file name then use `sed` to `s`ubstitute the first(! and first only) occurence of `A` with `B` (this can also be `sed 's/this123/that456/'`, but be aware that it will match the first hit)

For making sure it behaves as expected, run this first:

```
for f in filep-* ; do echo mv -iv "$f" "$(echo "$f" | sed 's/p/q/')" ; done
```

This will just print the command to be executed for each file and should look like `mv -i filep-x fileq-x`.

Note: this is for renaming the files and thus for after you copied them. This does not do the copying and renaming in one. Also it is meant to be executed form the directory where the files are.

Comment: I'm assuming you did not actually test your code, because the `for ... in ... done` commands, as written, couldn't possibly execute properly as you've referenced `"$file"` but not assigned it! It should be `"$f"` not `"$file"`. Also, you're attempting to move a file that doesn't exist because `for f in fileq-*` is supposed to be `for f in filep-*`. The existing files have a `p` not `q` before the `-` in the OP and is supposed to be `q` as part of the rename. If I'm wrong about that, then your `sed` command would be wrong.

Comment: @user3439894 - Thanks for the corrections. I DID test the code, yet used different variables, hence the mix-up between `fileq-` and `filep-` as well as between `$file` and `$f` (this one happens to me in half of my `bash` scripts... a bad habit). - Updated.