# Bulk File Change from CSV in MacOS

Tags: terminal, csv

I'm trying to change about 50 file names using a CSV format. My CSV file is setup with Col A as Old Name and Col B as New Name. I'm running the following scripts in terminal:

I followed this guide: [Renaming files/names in bulk, any smarter solution?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/236213/renaming-files-names-in-bulk-any-smarter-solution?newreg=024daada8bb54e35a8677071528a9bf0)

But it wasn't working for me. I kept getting the error:
`mv: rename ﻿Screen Shot 2020-03-10 at 3.03.00 PM.png to Test 1.png: No such file or directory.`

I was in the correct directory and the file was also in that directory, so I'm not sure why it couldn't find it.

Is there an alternative way of bulk renaming in MacOS?

Comment: The spaces in your file name are probably causing an error. Try renaming the screenshot to a file name with no spaces. Or use the delimiter in your script.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Finder and go to the directory with the file names you want to change, then select the files you want to change the name of. Then go to the gear icon in the top of the Finder window, or just right-click on the files you selected. There is a command to change x-number of file names. See the first image below.

[image]

When you click on the rename x items you get the following pane.

[image]

From here you can set up the new file names.